# Not able plot to plot two subplots side by side two blank graphs are coming first then the others

Tags: pandas, seaborn, data-visualization, subplot

I'm trying to plot two lmplot using the seaborn library side by side but the results are weird.
First, two blank plots are coming followed by the desired output but in one color

The code I'm running:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
sns.lmplot(x='LSTAT',y='price',data=data,height=7,scatter_kws={'alpha':0.6,'s':50},line_kws={'color':'red'})

plt.subplot(1,2,2)

sns.lmplot(x='LSTAT',y='LOG_PRICE',data=transformed_data,height=7,scatter_kws={'alpha':0.6,'s':50},line_kws={'color':'#FF00FF'})


plt.show()
```

[image: Image for Reference:]

Comment: `lmplot` is the [figure-level](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions-(FAQs)#what-do-figure-level-and-axes-level-mean) version of `regplot`, meaning `lmplot` always creates its own figure and manages its own subplots based on params like `hue` and `col`. If you want to plot your grid using `lmplot`, you need to convert your dataframe to [long-form](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions-(FAQs)#how-does-my-data-need-to-be-organized) with a column that specifies whether a given row is log or not.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use regplot insead of lmplot, and specify the ax argument as the axis you want to plot on:

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(24,6) 
sns.regplot(x='LSTAT',y='price',data=data,scatter_kws={'alpha':0.6,'s':50},line_kws={'color':'red'},ax=axes[0])
  
        
sns.regplot(x='LSTAT',y='LOG_PRICE',data=transformed_data,scatter_kws={'alpha':0.6,'s':50},line_kws={'color':'#FF00FF'},ax=axes[1])
```

Comment: TypeError: lmplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ax' getting this error

Comment: Please, help me out

Comment: I edited my answer. please check and confirm

Comment: Two questions still in my mind 1) How to increase the size of the plots they are too small. 2) why did the lmplot method didn't worked?

Comment: I edited my answer and added figsize argument. lmplot doesn't support the ax argument, so regplot is the correct one for this.

Comment: Does this help?